# iOS Setup Geofences on launch best practice

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

So in my app on launch I am doing the following things:

1. Downloading a list of locations from my server
2. Comparing the user's current location with all the locations and saving the 20 closest ones
3. Removing the old list of registered Geofences (because the user's location may have changed) and stop monitoring them
4. Saving / Adding the new Geofences and begin region monitoring.

I know how to do all these things. The question is what would be the best way to do this since I don't actually have to update any view, nor will I be using the users location anywhere else in the app? Should I create a singleton to do this? If I do essentially it will have to do all these on initialization and it seems unlikely that I would ever have to access it in the app again.

I was thinking to write everything in the AppDelegate potentially for two reasons:

1. The Delegate Methods `- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didEnterRegion:(CLRegion *)region` will be taken care of in the AppDelegate when the Geofence is triggered while the app is not running so it makes sense to put all the other delegates here as well like:
2. Also in the future there may be a requirement to call

   ```
   - (void) locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation
   ```

   To track significant changes in user location to update the geofences to get the new 20 closest. Since this will also be called in the background and in the app delegate maybe it will be best.

Or any other ideas.

Comment: you just asked 4 different questions in one. We cant just tell you the best way. You  mentioned that you know how to do it, then you should also mentioned how you want to do it, then we might suggest the best way.

Comment: I would recommend against putting it all in the AppDelegate.  I would put it in a new class, say, XXGeofenceManager, that is created and invoked from the AppDelegate, to separate the concerns of managing your app from managing the geofences.  Otherwise your AppDelegate will get awfully cluttered as you keep adding more and more stuff to it.

Comment: @Mr.T I didn't ask four different questions I asked 1. I was asking if it make sense to put it in a singleton or in the app delegate or some other method. I already know how to do all the things listed individually (which is stated in the question).

Comment: @EricGalluzzo when you say one class you mean as a singleton I presume? I suppose that would be the best way, but how would the singleton interact with methods that are called when the app is still technically in the background? Would I just make them static methods?

Comment: @AudreyHipburn I don't necessary mean a true singleton.  You would only create one instance, via [[XXGeofenceManager alloc] init], and hold onto that instance in your AppDelegate.  If you have other methods, e.g. on the AppDelegate, that are called in the background, just forward those calls onto the XXGeofenceManager.  Or if your geofence manager is a CLLocationManagerDelegate and you want to call the AppDelegate, just create a protocol that the AppDelegate implements, hold onto a weak reference to it in XXGeofenceManager, and forward on to that.  Dependency Inversion Principle, you know. :)

Comment: @EricGalluzzo thanks! My geofencemanager IS a CLLocationManagerDelegate but why would I need to all the AppDelegate?

 Also my AppDelegate is also a delegate of CLLocationManager because of `locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didEnterRegion:(CLRegion *)region` being called without waking up the entire app which means I would have to instantiate my GeofenceManager again?

Comment: @AudreyHipburn I don't think you should need to call the AppDelegate from your geofence manager -- I thought you were saying you needed to. :)  Also, I would not make AppDelegate a CLLocationManagerDelegate for the same reason as I wouldn't put all the geofence stuff in there -- too much clutter, and it will end up just getting bigger and bigger.  Instead, if the only reason you are using Core Location is for geofencing, just make your geofence manager the CLLocationManagerDelegate, and make it hold the CLLocationManager as well.

Comment: @EricGalluzzo sounds good. I'll give it a shot. I assumed that in the background only AppDelegate would be called. But if the GeofenceManager is called that'll probably work. How do I mark you ask answer?

Comment: @AudreyHipburn I'll write a new answer containing the salient points and you can mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend against cluttering up the AppDelegate with lots of geofencing code.  It will tend only to get bigger and bigger (and more unmaintainable) over time.  Separation of concerns would tend to suggest that this code should be moved into a separate class.  With that in mind, my recommendation would be:

- Create a new geofence manager class, say, XXGeofenceManager.
- Move your CLLocationManager into XXGeofenceManager, and make XXGeofenceManager conform to CLLocationManagerDelegate (i.e. move this code from your AppDelegate to your geofence manager).
- Create a single instance of XXGeofenceManager in your AppDelegate, and hold onto it in an instance variable.  Then invoke some method on it to install your geofences when the app starts, and leave the rest of your functionality in the geofence manager.

That way, you will hopefully end up just adding a couple lines to AppDelegate, and all your geofence-related code will end up in one place.

Hope that helps!